# Adding specific touch event to UIButton iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I am trying to add a touch to `UIButton`.

I want it to be when I click on button, until I release the finger, it won't click on it.

I Have played with many touch events, `Touch down, Touch up inside` etc but none is working like that. This is a very common touch event. How can I add such a thing in iPhone `UIButton`?

Comment: "Touch Down" does this, it does not want till you release the finger for sure.

Comment: it doesn/t i have tried. as soon as i put my finger touch down performs click event

Comment: Your requirement is not clear, Can you explain clearly ? Do you want to wait till you release the finger ? or do you want to fire the event without waiting for release ?

Comment: I need to wait till i release my finger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Touch up inside** is the event you should use here. If it doesn't work, that means you haven't implemented it correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Touch up inside** will only execute when you `remove your finger` from the button

**Touch down event** will work as soon as you `touch the button`.

Sample Project:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hm82u553ktyszbd/ST-16385963.zip

Answer (score 0):

Could you post your code? It sounds like you want the Touch Up Inside functionality of not firing until the finger is raised.